# Invalid year/week combination in PHP on first days of the year

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, php-carbon

Why does this happen (might be cause `Carbon` extends `DateTime` and this http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php#114366) and how to get the correct week from the `Carbon` instance when changing timezone?

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$wet = Carbon::parse( '2017-01-02 00:47:21', 'WET' );
$cet = Carbon::parse( '2017-01-02 00:47:21', 'CET' );

$new = $cet->copy()->tz( 'WET' );

print_r( [

    'cet->format(ATOM)' => $cet->format( Carbon::ATOM ),    //prints: 2017-01-02T00:47:21+01:00
    'cet->format(Y  W)' => $cet->format( 'Y  W' ),          //prints: 2017  01

    'wet->format(ATOM)' => $wet->format( Carbon::ATOM ),    //prints: 2017-01-02T00:47:21+00:00
    'wet->format(Y  W)' => $wet->format( 'Y  W' ),          //prints: 2017  01

    'new->format(ATOM)' => $new->format( Carbon::ATOM ),    //prints: 2017-01-01T23:47:21+00:00
    'new->format(Y  W)' => $new->format( 'Y  W' ),          //prints: 2017  52

] );
```

One more simple case:

```
print_r( [
    Carbon::create( 2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 )->format( 'Y  W' ),        //prints: 2017  52
    Carbon::create( 2016, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 )->format( 'Y  W' ),   //prints: 2016  52
] );
```

Comment: Well, those local times have a 1-hour offset. Switching from 00:47 results in 23:47 **from previous day**. What result were you expecting?

Comment: It turns out it's the date that's the problem, not timezone itself. When the date changes to a day before the first Monday of the current year, then the `weekOfYear` field changes, but not the actual `year`. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the day is before the 1st week in the year, (ex: 1st of January 2017)
it returns 52, but doesn't change the actual year (returns 2017 instead of 2016), so I'm forcing the instance to the last second of the previous year to get the correct week

```
if (50 < $new->weekOfYear && 2 > $new->month)
{
    $new->year( $new->year - 1 )->endOfYear();
}

echo $new->format( 'Y  W' ); //prints: 2016  52
```

Comment: As [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) explain, `W` is   ISO-8601 week number of year. That *not* the row number in your wall calendar, which I suspect is what you were expecting.

Comment: I was expecting the correct W to be 52, I wasn't expecting the year to remain 2017... When formatting with only 'W' you see no problem, but when combining 'Y  W' for 1st of January, it turns it to '2017  52' - which I wasn't expecting. I needed it to be '2016  52'.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've changed the title as to not mislead others.

Comment: If you start on 2nd January 2017 and switch to another time zone you'd need a 25-hour offset to end up on 31st December 2016. DST probably makes that technically possible but not in present time and Europe.

Comment: I don't need the timestamp to be correct, that's why I use `copy()` on the instance. I just need the formatted string 'Y  W'

Comment: btw, 2nd of January 2017 also is in the 52nd week :)